# Stripe Checkout on app hosted on Heroku - ensuring secure payments (SSL)

Tags: node.js, heroku, stripe-payments

I have an app hosted on Heroku (still in development and not live) which is an online course. Users can sign up for free and they get access to the free video section. The free video section has a Stripe Payment button. If users which to become members then they can make payment and will gain access to the 'membership' video section of the app once payment is successful.

My question is to do with SSL and taking payment. I have asked this question to Stripe and they have responded:*

*Yes, you'd have to set up a TSL/SSL certificate for PCI compliance. Since you're using Heroku, I'd recommend reaching out to their customer support for more information on that.*

I then spoke to Heroku and they said to contact Stripe...

As I'm not very experienced in this area, can someone recommend what I need to do? Do I need to activate SSL when the Stripe Checkout pop up is activated. Does Stripe Checkout even need SSL or is it already secure?

Further information: I'm using Heroku Professional Standard package.

I have found the following from Stripes website:

*PCI compliance is a shared responsibility and applies to both Stripe and your business. When accepting payments, you must do so in a PCI compliant manner. The simplest way for you to be PCI compliant is to never see (or have access to) card data at all. Stripe makes this easy for you as we can do the heavy lifting to protect your customers’ card information. You can simplify your PCI compliance as long as you:*

*Use Checkout, Stripe.js and Elements, or our mobile SDK libraries to collect payment information, which is securely transmitted directly to Stripe without it passing through your servers*

I'm pretty sure as I'm using Stripe Checkout then I do not need to do anything further, but just want to be 100% sure before I start taking payments...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Even if Stripe Checkout itself is served over HTTPS from Stripe's servers, your payment page including Stripe Checkout also needs to be served over HTTPS with a valid TLS certificate in order for you to be [PCI compliant](https://stripe.com/docs/security#validating-pci-compliance).

(Technically, if your site was served over unencrypted HTTP, an attacker could do a man-in-the-middle attack and change `https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js` with the URL to a malicious script.)

You should simply ask Heroku to help you setup HTTPS on your site -- the fact that you're using Stripe is just context for *why* you need this, but it doesn't change anything for Heroku.

Comment: Thanks. According to this page: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint there seems to be an additional charge for custom domains ($20/month). 

I guess this is the route I'm going to have to take. Sure makes hosting an app expensive :(

I suppose I can just get my domain to redirect to my Heroku app so that I do not need to set up a custom domain (as Heroku apps comes HTTPS as standard).